# Spring bind not working in velocity template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I have added a object to the command in spring bean. I am using that command in y velocity template and trying to bind the new object i created using springFormInput. I am using velocity template. Here is the syntax

```
#springFormInput("command.newObject.newName", "class=s11")
```

I do not see that the data i am entering here as text in the form is not getting bind to the command.

Any idea on why this is not working. There are some other fields in form like checkbox and they are binding. Its only this new object that i created in the command does not seem to be working. Pls help.

Answer (score -1):

I have something in the controller class where the controller has objects defined in it that allows binds. So when i specified the objects there under allow binding form, I could see the spring bind is working.